# Philips headlight bulb Confusing power?

Tags: headlight

Just going throw the subject 
I have get tired of OEM bulb especially on highway road cannot see good and feel no safety 
So i decide to  change to performance bulb and i found philips xtream vision 9005 for lo beam but 
The problem is the philips bulb said on box of bulb 65w but the bulb it self has 2 diffrent value 
Said 
hb3 12v E1 22s 60w
 9005 12v 65w
And my factory bulb is
Sylvania 9005 12v 60w 
I am really confused ???  I want install the performance philips but am worry about diffrent watt 
Please need your help to explane this matter ???

[image: this the original bulb that came installed in in my car and what "E1" 22n mean ?]

[image: again what " E1" Means ? and as you can see two power info one 60 and 65]

Answer (score 1):

You'll be fine installing that bulb, if it fits.

OEM bulb manufacturers play fast and loose with their ratings.  It's not always about the "wattage" in terms of power consumption... sometimes they make an "equivalent" statement about perceived brightness.

In essence, they use different color coatings to shift the spectrum towards "blue", which may appear "brighter" to the eye and illuminates reflective coatings on road signs better.

Whether or not these bulbs are really "brighter", "safer" is a matter of great debate.  Check out Daniel Stern's lighting page for and endless rant on this topic.

It all boils down to the color spectrum.  Bulbs that throw more blue spectrum appear "brighter", but that may be because they are throwing more glare.  Your brain perceives this to be "brighter", but only because the glare forces your brain to close  your eye iris to some degree. According to Dan Stern, this really isn't as helpful as it would seem.  "Yellow" spectrum of light provides greater *actual* illumination, allowing you eye to dilate more and get more information.  The yellow spectrum is particularly helpful for dealing with foggy/snowy conditions.  Blue spectrum bulbs tend to reflect a lot of extra light off the "fog", and *seem* brighter - except the fog isn't what you need to see clearly.

I know a great deal about this topic, and yet I actually know nothing.  More TRUE wattage is always better, but you often have to order actual high-wattage bulbs through a back-door [often European] source.  They are probably not technically legal, and your wiring/sockets may not be able to handle the extra heat and wattage such bulbs entail.

In any case, I see no problem in installing that bulb.  I hope it helps. 5W is not going to make a difference.  Your better solution may be aftermarket "driving" or "fog" lights - which will allow you to put another 120-200 watts of illumination out there.  More bulbs are better; "superbulbs" may be a compromise and expense that doesn't achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you for the information so it should be ok install the philips 65 W and btw i have wattge meter ans i mesure the current power from the sylvania oem bulb and xtream philps  the result is the oem bulb give 4.95amp and 61.1W  the performamce philips give 4.89amp and 62W  so the real diffrence is 1W !!!??

Comment: As I expected, electrically these bulbs are virtually identical.  You would have to measure the voltage drop across the bulbs while running, and also compare output with a lumen light meter.  It probably isn't worth the effort.  If you feel the new bulbs "work" better, good.  But I would still read Daniel Stern's Lighting page about "myths" and "blue tinted" bulbs.